# Name Error Help in a loop

Tags: python-3.x

**Observed Behavior or what happened?**

It gives the error `"if changeto == 'RIGHT' and not direction == 'LEFT':"`, also it is suppose to change the screen color, but does not.

**Expected Behavior?**

The background is suppose to change to white and show a "snake" in the color of green.

**Where I think the problem might be.**

Before I can troubleshoot the other issues I need to find the main one. Which is `"if changeto == 'RIGHT' and not direction == 'LEFT':"` When I look at the issue I can narrow it down to this area:

```
    # Main Logic, Direction Buttons

while True:
    for  event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('r'):
                changeto = 'RIGHT'
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('l'):
                changeto = 'LEFT'
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('u'):
                changeto = 'UP' 
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('d'):
                changeto = 'DOWN'
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event(QUIT))
```

**Full Code?**
If needed, the full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ef8001e10ca59f5165ec765cc80bcda).

I know it is probably something very simple, and I may just be over looking. Thank for the help.

Comment: The basic intuition is that you can change your direction to any one that is not diametrically opposite to your current direction of movement. But what's the problem?

Comment: post the traceback and error message

Comment: I figured it out. thanks